# new does not allocate memory

Tags: c++, memory

This should fill my memory every second with ca 100 MB. I track the memoryusage with gnome-systemmonitor and htop. But somehow it does not.  Why?

```
#include "unistd.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (true){
        std::cout << "New one" << std::endl;
        new char[100000000];
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To run:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O0  main.cpp; ./a.out
```

Comment: Lazy allocation, most likely. Try writing something to the allocated array.

Comment: I originally thought it was related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25668420/1708801) but it seems even with `5.1` gcc does not do the same optimization with new that clang does and [godbolt shows gcc does call new](http://goo.gl/zXaTlQ) ... so Paul is likely correct ... clang on the other hand will optimize the call to new away at `-O1` and greater.

Comment: You are aware the 100MB would be char[104857600]? I guess that the new command gets optimized out because it has no reason to be there...

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thats why I used -O0

Comment: @Nidhoegger yes, thats why I wrote circa.

Comment: You are not allocating any memory.  On any modern demand-paged virtual memory operating system like OSX, Linux, Windows you are only allocating address space.  A 64-bit OS has as much as 256 Terabytes available.  So you are probably just not waiting long enough, it takes 256E12 / 1E8 * sleep(1) = 256E4 msec = 2560 seconds.  Almost 3/4 of an hour.  Removing the sleep(1) call makes it a lot quicker :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're not using it, Linux does lazy allocation so it will not actually map any memory page until you use it.

If you put some code like:

```
char* test = new char[100000000];
test[0] = 'a';
test[4096] = 'b';
...
```

You should see it's actually consuming your system memory.

Answer (score 2):

I have only seen [clang optimize away calls to new](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25668420/1708801) and in general a compiler will not perform such aggressive optimizations when you are using `-O0`.

We can see from [godbolt](http://goo.gl/zXaTlQ) that `gcc` indeed does not optimize away the call to `new` in very similar code:

```
.L2:
 movl   $100000000, %edi
 call   operator new[](unsigned long)
 movl   $1, %edi
 call   sleep
 jmp    .L2
```

So most likely [Paul is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944433/new-does-not-allocate-memory/29944699#comment48009663_29944433) and lazy allocation is involved and therefore once you write to the allocated memory you will see it being used.