# I think I can understand §5.3.4/11 in N4140, but the notion of an allocation function which has been extended is incomprehensible to me

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, new-operator, c++14

The two paragraphs below were copied from N4140 (emphasis are mine).

§5.3.4/11:

> When a *new-expression* calls an allocation function and that
>   allocation has **not** **been extended**, the *new-expression* passes the
>   amount of space requested to the allocation function as the first
>   argument of type `std::size_t`. That argument shall be no less than
>   the size of the object being created; it may be greater than the size
>   of the object being created only if the object is an array. For
>   arrays of `char` and `unsigned char`, the difference between the
>   result of the *new-expression* and the address returned by the
>   allocation function shall be an integral multiple of the strictest
>   fundamental alignment requirement (3.11) of any object type whose size
>   is no greater than the size of the array being created. [ Note:
>   Because allocation functions are assumed to return pointers to storage
>   that is appropriately aligned for objects of any type with fundamental
>   alignment, this constraint on array allocation overhead permits the
>   common idiom of allocating character arrays into which objects of
>   other types will later be placed. —end note ]

§5.4.3/12

> When a *new-expression* calls an allocation function and that
>   allocation **has** **been extended**, the size argument to the
>   allocation call shall be no greater than the sum of the sizes for
>   the omitted calls as specified above, plus the size for the extended
>   call had it not been extended, plus any padding necessary to align the
>   allocated objects within the allocated memory.

I can understand §5.3.4/11, but the notion of an allocation function which has been extended is incomprehensible to me, as stated above in §5.4.3/12.

Comment: That basically means that instead of allocating `sizeof(class)` 1000 times, the compiler can allocate `sizeof(class) * 1000` one time if the criteria mentioned in /12 are met.

Answer (score 6):

This language was added by [N3664: Clarifying Memory Allocation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3664.html) which allows the implementation to fuse allocations when the allocations are not part of the observable behavior. In other words the allocation can be *extended*.

The function call itself is not extended but the function call and hence the allocation *may be omitted* and the *allocations may be lumped* together into a larger allocation later on.

The proposal states the problem (*emphasis mine*):

> As strict reading of the current C and C++ standards may lead one to
>   conclude that the allocation strategy shall not consider any
>   information not derivable from the sequence of new and delete
>   expressions. In essence, the standards may exclude macro-optimization
>   of allocation.
>
> On the other hand, a **strict reading of the standards may lead one to
>   conclude that the implementation must make an allocation function call
>   for each and every new expression**. This reading may exclude
>   micro-optimization of allocation.

and proposes:

> We propose to replace existing mechanistic wording with wording more
>   precisely focused on essential requirements. **The intent is to enable
>   behavior that some existing compilers and memory allocators already
>   have**. For example, see TCMalloc

and further says:

> An essential requirement on implementations is that they deliver
>   usable memory, **not that they have a particular sequence of allocation
>   calls**. We propose to relax the allocation calls with respect to new
>   expressions.
>
> 1. Within certain constraints, the number of allocation calls is not part of the observable behavior of the program. This **enables
>      implementations to reduce the number of allocation calls by avoiding
>      them or fusing them**.
> 2. When avoiding or fusing allocations, the amount of space requested does not exceed that implied by the new expressions, with the
>      exception of additional padding to meet alignment constraints. This
>      means that the amount of space allocated does not increase peak
>      allocation.
>
> Because C++ class-specific memory allocators are often tuned to
>   specific class sizes, we do not apply this relaxation to those
>   allocators.

This can lead to allocations being completely omitted which can be surprising in some cases. We can see for the following example taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31873616/1708801):

```
#include <new>  

int main()
{
    int* mem = new (std::nothrow) int[100];
    return 0;
}
```

clang optimizes this to (*[see it live via godbolt](http://goo.gl/wvPt6B)*):

```
main:                                   # @main
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    retq
```

This is allowable because no observable behavior is effected, so this falls under the umbrella of the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Comment: I still can't see the relationship between the optimization in your example and §5.4.3/12

Comment: @Belloc explaining that optimization is rather involved [my answer to the question I linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31877074/1708801) explains the logic that allows it. It basically comes down to the *as-if rule*. Once we are allowed to omit allocations calls whether an optimization is allowed comes down to whether it effects observable behavior or not.