# Should I compare a std::string to "string" or "string"s?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, string-comparison, string-literals

Consider this code snippet:

```
bool foo(const std::string& s) {
    return s == "hello"; // comparing against a const char* literal
}

bool bar(const std::string& s) {
    return s == "hello"s; // comparing against a std::string literal
}
```

At [first sight](https://godbolt.org/z/fIppl1), it looks like comparing against a `const char*` needs less assembly instructions<sup>1</sup>, as using a string literal will lead to an in-place construction of the `std::string`.

*(**EDIT: As pointed out in the answers, I forgot about the fact that effectively `s.compare(const char*)` will be called in `foo()`, so of course no in-place construction takes place in this case. Therefore striking out some lines below.**)*

<strike>However, looking at the [`operator==(const char*, const std::string&)` reference:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)</strike>

> All comparisons are done via the `compare()` member function.

From my understanding, this means that we will need to construct a `std::string` anyway in order to perform the comparison, so I suspect the overhead will be the same in the end (although hidden by the call to `operator==`).

- Which of the comparisons should I prefer?
- Does one version have advantages over the other (may be in specific situations)?

*<sup>1</sup> I'm aware that less assembly instructions doesn't neccessarily mean faster code, but I don't want to go into micro benchmarking here.*

Comment: `return s == "hello";`.

Comment: better use `-O2/3` for the comparison, i mean who cares how many instructions it is in a debug build ? ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No it isn't. It's a case of not writing needlessly wasteful code. The choice between a string literal and a needless string instantiation is not a micro optimisation; it's common sense! In other words, this _is_ about writing good code.

Comment: See overload (4) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare

Comment: There is too much bloaty and slow code in the world at the moment because people consider writing good code that doesn't do more that it needs to, to be "premature optimisation" and have been scared away from thinking about the code they're writing as a result :(

Comment: `"hello"s` constructor calls `new`, it can throw. Making the strings a little bit longer, and you can see [the difference](https://godbolt.org/z/UWe2XX).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this doesn't have _anything_ to do with premature optimization, I'm asking out of curiosity in the first place and also this would affect coding style to some extent. You don't tell people to pass `const A` vs. `const A&` in the general case just because they shouldn't care about "premature optimization"

Comment: @molbdnilo of course - I was so focused on the actual problem that I forgot about this :-) - fixed.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

### Neither.

If you want to be clever, compare to [`"string"sv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv), which returns a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).

---

While comparing against a literal like `"string"` does not result in any allocation-overhead, it's treated as a null terminated string, with all the concomittant disadvantages: No tolerance for embedded nulls, and users must heed the null terminator.

`"string"s` does an allocation, barring [small-string-optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425276/inconsistent-behavior-of-compiler-optimization-of-unused-string) or [allocation elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873616/is-the-compiler-allowed-to-optimize-out-heap-memory-allocations). Also, the operator gets passed the length of the literal, no need to count, and it allows for embedded nulls.

And finally using `"string"sv` combines the advantages of both other approaches, avoiding their individual disadvantages. Also, a `std::string_view` is a far simpler beast than a `std::string`, especially if the latter uses SSO as all modern ones do.

---

At least since C++14 (which generally allowed eliding allocations), compilers could in theory optimise all options to the last one, given sufficient information (generally available for the example) and effort, under the [as-if rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule). We aren't there yet though.

Comment: the idea sound sane but there isn't a `std::string::compare(string_view ...)` function or `operator ==` defined between `std::string` and `std::string_view`

Comment: @xception Yes there is. Unfortunately the standard talks about newer overloads like that in incredibly arcane terms for very little good reason (rather than the good old-fashioned method of just listing overloads and their simple arguments). But it's [7-9 here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) that you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry what's the benefit of this over a simple string literal? Don't get me wrong, I love string views and make judicious use of them when appropriate, but I'm not seeing it here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit awesome, didn't know that, thanks for the info

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit We tried just saying `string_view`. Turns out that breaks existing code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It can first compare the sizes, and than do a sized memory-comparison. That can be optimised better than always staying on the lookout for the terminator. Also, it allows embedded nulls if wanted.

Comment: @Deduplicator Surely a sane implementation will just `strlen` up front? Which is effectively equivalent. And if the implementer decided that it's cheaper _not_ to `strlen` up front then they have the freedom to do so .. but they don't if you use a string_view.

Comment: in fact, with `-O3` gcc seems even to be able to [inline the call to `compare`](https://godbolt.org/z/pQ2r7m), which doesn't happen with the regular string literal.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There is no `strlen()` for creating the string_view using `operator "" sv`.

Comment: And I'd just gone and found https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc#L1429, too. Oh well. Can you add into your answer that the length can be baked into the SV construction at compile-time? I think that's the major key of your suggestion, and (assuming other people are stupid like me) it's not obvious from your wording.

Comment: Using string_view [looks](https://godbolt.org/z/jVUzSd) the fastest on `gcc9.1 -Ofast` because of inlining the call to compare. With `-Os` both string_view and string literal version call `memcmp`.

Comment: Really nice answer, thanks! `std::string_view` really never crossed my mind in this case, but seems to be indeed an optimal solution!

Comment: [Inconsistent behavior of compiler optimization of unused string](//stackoverflow.com/q/56425276) has some details about optimizing away construction of a `std::string` with gcc vs. clang and libstdc++ vs. libc++.  (clang can optimize away `delete new ...` but gcc can't, so only short `std::string` objects can optimize away.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I incorporated some more links and background info. Still, *all* the user-defined literals the standard library provides are in their respective namespace under std::literals, with all but std being inline-namespaces, [those for `std::string` are not exempt](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2b066f32c3fc1ef).

Comment: Oops, I missed that the OP's godbolt link already included `using namespace std::string_literals;`.  That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Question: does a string literal such as `"hello"s` get allocated at compile time, or is there some overhead every time it's used? Or something in between?

Comment: @EdwardFalk "hello"s is a function-call returning a temporary, despite its curious looks.

Answer (score 15):

No, `compare()` does not require construction of a `std::string` for `const char*` operands.

You're using [overload #4 here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare).

The comparison to string literal is the "free" version you're looking for. Instantiating a `std::string` here is completely unnecessary.

Comment: "Free" only if the implementation of the suitable `compare` function doesn't itself create a `std::string` object (although that's probably very unlikely).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Free at this level of abstraction, yes. Theoretically the implementation could be designed to hive off the comparison to the cloud, resulting in multi-millisecond latency and potentially a login to Facebook - but let's be real ;)

Comment: (However that is indeed why I used quotes cos nothing's truly free really)

Comment: Hm, maybe I am missing/overlooking something here but how does it _not_ need to construct a `std::string` if `compare` is a member function (non-static)?

Comment: @andreee Because `s == "hello"` is equal to `s.operator==("hello")`. You already have the `std::string` object with `s`.

Comment: @andreee `s` is already a `std::string` object.  The question is whether it can be compared against a character literal or only a `std::string`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't consider `this` on the left hand side :-) However, what about the string literal case? Why do I get it "for free"? From what I understand, I am comparing _two_ `std::string`s (the one that is passed vs. the literal that needs to be constructed). Where is the trick?

Comment: I don't understand where you imagine the `std::string` construction to come from. You have a `std::string` on the left (already exists; it's yours) and a `const char*` on the right. That's it. The function compares the string with the C-string. That's it.

Comment: I might not be explaining it properly, but I am talking about the `s == "hello"s"` case (not `const char*`). I have a `std::string` on the left hand side, but then also a `std::string` (constructed from the string literal) on the right side that I thought must be constructed before comparison.

Comment: @andreee Yes, but that's not the case we're talking about. We're talking about why the string literal version is better _because_ it isn't that. It's possible we're using the term "string literal" differently. We commonly understand this to mean the C-string literal version.

Comment: Okay I see. _"The comparison to string literal is the "free" version you're looking for."_: By string literal you seem to be talking about plain old C literals, while I was thinking of `std::string_literals`. This might be the problem :-)

Comment: @andreee: Yup, that's a terminology problem: `"hello"` *is* called a "string literal" in both C and C++ terminology.  If you mean a `std::string` literal, you need to say "std::string literal", or possibly "`string` literal" with code just formatting, but the latter is still potentially confusing.

Answer (score 9):

> From my understanding, this means that we will need to construct a `std::string` anyway in order to perform the comparison, so I suspect the overhead will be the same in the end (although hidden by the call to `operator==`).

This is where that reasoning goes wrong. [`std::compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) does not need to allocate its operand as a C-style null-terminated string to function. According to one of the overloads:

```
int compare( const CharT* s ) const; // (4)
```

> 4) Compares this string to the null-terminated character sequence beginning at the character pointed to by `s` with length `Traits::length(s)`.

Although whether to allocate or not is an implementation detail, it does not seem reasonable that a sequence comparison would do so.