# What are differences in the different build types when it comes to optimization in the GCC complier for C++ (CLion)?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, clion, ram

FYI: I am in CLion.
This is just something I am curious about, but I made a program to use all my ram for fun. It created a `int* array = new int[3'900'000'000]{};`.

When I run this program in debug build option, it does use all of my ram. But in the release mode, it doesn't use up any of my ram. I even tried to modify certain values in the array to see if that would force the complier to create the full array. When in the release mode, I also tried to fill every single number in the array with something with the `fill` method and manually using a `for` loop.

Comment: ***it doesn't use up any of my ram.*** Your compiler probably figured out that your modifying of the array was pointless and eliminated it.

Comment: That's also what I was thinking, but why is it different in debug?

Comment: Debug does not do optimizations like this / code elimination.

Comment: [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)

Comment: `What are differences in the different build types` What is a "build type"? Gcc compiler has no "build types", it has specific options. I think this is a question specifically about how specifically clion IDE defines "build types". Is "build type" something you choose in clion? I do not use clion, I think this question should be tagged with clion.

Comment: That's part of the reason why I included specifically that I was on CLion, but since it uses gcc I included GCC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cpp
int* array = new int[3'900'000'000]{};
```

was probably optimized out by the compiler because it realized that this memory isn't used, and the allocation isn't necessary.

This optimization is called *heap elision*.
See also [Is the compiler allowed to optimize out heap memory allocations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31873616/5740428)

In general, compilers will attempt to optimize your code in every conceivable way, as long as the observable behavior remains the same.
They do this according to the as-if rule. See also [What exactly is the "as-if" rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15718262/5740428)

Use [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fabaedbEj) to gain an understanding of what optimizations are actually applied. For example, GCC with optimization enabled (`-O2`) optimizes

```cpp
int main() {
    int* array = new int[3'900'000'000]{};
}
```

to

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

It's as if the allocation never happened. A way to trick the compiler and disable optimizations is to use `volatile`:

```cpp
int main() {
    volatile int* array = new int[3'900'000'000]{};
    delete array;
}
```

The compiler cannot optimize this out because `volatile` reads and writes *are* considered observable behavior.
However, you might get `std::bad_alloc` because the allocation is too large.

Comment: A more complicated example would be to put some values into at least some of the array. The compiler can eliminate that again by the "as-if" rule if it determines the act of filling values in the array is not needed for the observable behavior.