# Documentation of "invalid pointer value" conversion in C++ implementations

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer

According to the C++ Standard, it is mandatory for every implementation to document "implementation-defined behavior":

> 1.3.11 `[defns.impl.defined]` **implementation-defined behavior**
>
> behavior, for a well-formed program construct and correct data, that depends on the implementation and that each implementation documents

And reading an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior (see 4.1 Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion `[conv.lval]`):

> if the object to which the glvalue refers contains an invalid pointer value (3.7.4.2, 3.7.4.3), the behavior is implementation-defined.

(quote from draft n4527, but verbiage that "Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior. Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior." has been in 3.7.4.2 Deallocation functions `[basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]` since at least draft n3485)

However, many popular implementations do not define this behavior, and many experts describe this as "undefined behavior" instead.

A likely cause for omission of clear documentation is that, as far as I can determine, evaluation of "invalid pointer values" is missing from the "Index of implementation-defined behavior" which appears in Standard drafts following the appendices.

Is this a defect in the Standard, and are there any open Defect Reports or committee actions taken since C++14 concerning it?

Comment: Seems to me the part that implementations need to define is this - *Some implementations might define that copying an invalid pointer value causes a system-generated runtime fault.* (footnote under §3.7.4.3). You should be able to determine from your processor's documentation whether specific bit patterns loaded into some address register will cause a fault.

Comment: So your question is why is this not documented in the *Index of implementation-defined behavior*?

Comment: @Praetorian: Behavior of C++ programs is most certainly not identical to behavior documented by the CPU vendor (consider a loop condition that terminates only upon signed-integer wraparound -- the CPU may well define that wraparound occurs, but the C++ optimizer is perfectly entitled to treat it as an infinite loop)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Essentially, yes.  It could be that it isn't there because it's actually meant to be undefined behavior, and the other sections have a typo.  Or maybe there's already a suggested rewording that the committee hasn't yet voted on.  Or maybe it IS in the index, using a phrasing I didn't recognize as being related.  These are the types of things I'm trying to learn.

Comment: I have always found "implementation-defined behavior" a strange concept, as it only constrains compiler documentation authors and not programmers or compiler writers. (Either you are coding portably, in which case "implementation-defined" and "undefined" behaviors must be avoided equally; or you are coding for a specific platform, in which case all you care about is what your compiler guarantees and the spec's distinctions are irrelevant.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[CWG #1438](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1438) changed the semantics concerning invalid pointer values:

> The current Standard says that any use of an invalid pointer value
>   produces undefined behavior (3.7.4.2 [basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]
>   paragraph 4). This includes not only dereferencing the pointer but
>   even just fetching its value. The reason for this draconian
>   restriction is that some architectures in the past used dedicated
>   address registers for pointer loads and stores and they could fault
>   if, for example, a segment number in a pointer was not currently
>   mapped. 
> It is not clear whether such restrictions are necessary with
>   architectures currently in use or reasonably foreseen. This should be
>   investigated to see if the restriction can be loosened to apply only
>   to dereferencing the pointer.

The change in [conv.lval] is the resolution of [CWG #616](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#616), which essentially adopted the above.
Lifting this from UB to implementation-defined behavior was intentional, so I presume the absence of this paragraph in the Index is an oversight.