# Accessing invalid pointer and taking its address

Tags: c++, memory, stl

Consider a code like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec { 1, 2, 3 };
auto addr = &*vec.end();
```

or simplified:

```
int* ptr = 0;
auto addr = &*ptr;
```

It's obvious that `auto val = *ptr;` would segfault. Hence `&*ptr` is not accessing memory in the same way. Why is that the case? Is there a specific entry in standard for that?

Comment: "It's obvious that `auto val = *ptr;` would segfault." - it is? You would *hope* it would segfault, as that would make it far easier to discover your code has a defect, but alas invocation of *undefined behavior* (which happened the moment you applied the dereference operator to the container end-iterator) has no guarantees it will segfault, have all the appearance of "working", or anything else. The behavior is *undefined*; you can't rule *anything* out except definition of behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Dereferencing the return value of `std::vector::end()` is cause for undefined behavior. There is no point trying to make sense of what happens if you do.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end:

> This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.

Re. the second part, the only thing I could find in the C++11 standard is:

> **5.3.1 Unary operators**
>
> 1 The unary `*` operator performs *indirection*: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression is “pointer to `T`,” the type of the result is “`T`.” [ *Note:* a pointer to an incomplete type (other than *cv* `void`) can be dereferenced. The lvalue thus obtained can be used in limited ways (to initialize a reference, for example); this lvalue must not be converted to a
> prvalue, see 4.1. — *end note* ]

The result of dereferencing a NULL pointer seems to be unspecified.

Comment: that is not the question. See the 2nd example and explain why there is no seg fault

Comment: @PRP, the first of the question is just that.

Comment: The intended question is, while doing `auto addr = &(*ptr);` , isn't the pointer dereferenced first and then the address calculated. If yes, then why does the dereferencing of the pointer not give a seg fault.

Comment: @PRP, according to the OP, that's the simplified version of the first part of the question.

Comment: @PRP because the result of dereferencing a bad pointer is undefined. It could segfault. It could email an ascii art Mona Lisa to Cobra Commander. You don't know what it will do.

Comment: There are two related questions on SO: 

* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728299/why-is-comparing-against-end-iterator-legal


* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728299/why-is-comparing-against-end-iterator-legal

Note Stepanov's code in one and C standard quote in another.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases you end up computing addresses rather than accessing memory, that is why your code happens to work. But both cases are undefined behavior according to c++ standard. The first example may actually trigger an assertion  failure in Debug version of standard library.

Comment: That's the question: if that's the case, where in standard is this distinction (accessing memory vs "computing address") made?

Comment: There is no distinction in the standard,  both are undefined behavior. But in practice there is segfault only when the program needs to read contents of the memory.