# At which exact statement does this program exhibit Undefined behavior as per the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

<sub>(I am aware of the fact that returning address/reference to a variable local to the function should be avoided and a program should never do this.)</sub>

---

Does returning a reference to a local variable/reference result in Undefined Behavior? Or does the Undefined Behavior only occur later, when the returned reference is used (or "dereferenced")?

i.e. at what exact statement (`#1` or `#2` or `#3`) does code sample below invoke Undefined Behavior? (I've written my theory alongside each one)

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{ 
   int m_i;
   A():m_i(10)
   {

   } 
};  
A& foo() 
{     
    A a;
    a.m_i = 20;     
    return a; 
} 

int main()
{
   foo();                // #1 - Not UB; return value was never used
   A const &ref = foo(); // #2 - Not UB; return value still not yet used
   std::cout<<ref.m_i;   // #3 - UB: returned value is used
}
```

I am interested to know what the C++ standard specifies in this regard.

I would like a citation from the C++ standard which will basically tell me which exact statement makes this code ill-formed.

Discussions about how specific implementations handle this are welcome but as I said an ideal answer would cite an reference from the C++ Standard that clarifies this beyond doubt.

Comment: Line #2 does use the return value, as a copy-constructor is called. You should make main's `ref` an `A&`

Comment: "ref" is a local object, so,#3 should not be UB.

Comment: @iammilind: It quite obviously is UB. `ref` is a _reference_, referring to an object from another block scope that no longer exists.

Comment: @Als: Easy to fix that typo: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: @Als: Better to use `A const&` for #2, otherwise it won't compile. The semantics of what you're asking won't change though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, Thanks for pointing it out.Only a const reference can be bound to a temporary.I modified it.I guess its my bad I didn't compile it,Actually I just quickly grabbed it from a previous answer and modified it to suit the Q.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Whoops, what happened there  :-S Thanks for the fixed link!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Can you confirm what I said to iammilind? Never got my comment upvoted so I'm worried I'm going mad.

Comment: "ill-formed" and UB are two different things

Comment: @Als: Some people get jealous. Worst still, some people think that this site is only for "mentoring"/debugging questions, when in fact the opposite is true!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, when the reference is first initialised it is done so validly, satisfying the following:

> `[C++11: 8.3.2/5]:` There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references, and no pointers to references. The declaration of a reference shall contain an initializer (8.5.3) except when the declaration contains an explicit extern specifier (7.1.1), is a class member (9.2) declaration within a class definition, or is the declaration of a parameter or a return type (8.3.5); see 3.1. **A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function.** [ *Note:* in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by dereferencing a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior. As described in 9.6, a reference cannot be bound directly to a bit-field. *—end note* ]

The reference being returned from the function is an *xvalue*:

> `[C++11: 3.10/1]:` [..] An xvalue (an “eXpiring” value) also refers to an object, usually near the end of its lifetime (so that its resources may be moved, for example). An xvalue is the result of certain kinds of expressions involving rvalue references (8.3.2). [ *Example:* The result of calling a function whose return type is an rvalue reference is an xvalue. *—end example* ] [..]

That means the following does *not* apply:

> `[C++11: 12.2/1]:` Temporaries of class type are created in various contexts: binding a reference to a prvalue (8.5.3), **returning a prvalue (6.6.3)**, a conversion that creates a prvalue (4.1, 5.2.9, 5.2.11, 5.4), throwing an exception (15.1), entering a handler (15.3), and in some initializations (8.5).
>
> `[C++11: 6.6.3/2]:` A return statement with neither an *expression* nor a *braced-init-list* can be used only in functions that do not return a value, that is, a function with the return type void, a constructor (12.1), or a destructor (12.4).
>
> A return statement with an expression of non-void type can be used only in functions returning a value; the value of the expression is returned to the caller of the function. **The value of the expression is implicitly converted to the return type of the function in which it appears. A return statement can involve the construction and copy or move of a temporary object (12.2).** [ *Note:* A copy or move operation associated with a return statement may be elided or considered as an rvalue for the purpose of overload resolution in selecting a constructor (12.8). *—end note* ] A return statement with a *braced-init-list* initializes the object or reference to be returned from the function by copy-list-initialization (8.5.4) from the specified initializer list. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> std::pair<std::string,int> f(const char* p, int x) {
>    return {p,x};
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

Additionally, even if we interpret the following to mean that an initialisation of a new reference "object" is performed, the referee is *probably* still alive at the time:

> `[C++11: 8.5.3/2]:` A reference cannot be changed to refer to another object after initialization. Note that initialization of a reference is treated very differently from assignment to it. **Argument passing (5.2.2) and function value return (6.6.3) are initializations.**

- *This makes #1 valid.*

However, your initialisation of *a new reference `ref`* inside `main` quite clearly violates `[C++11: 8.3.2/5]`. I can't find wording for it, but it stands to reason that the function scope has been exited when the initialisation is performed.

- *This would make #2 (and consequently #3) invalid.*

At the very least, there does not appear to be anything further stated about the matter in the standard, so if the above reasoning is not sufficient then we have to conclude that the standard is ambiguous in the matter. Fortunately, it's of little consequence in practice, at least in the mainstream.

Comment: +1.For the effort and research.This looks promising.I am going to take some time to soak the relevant sections peacefully after work before I accept this answer.

Comment: The reference being returned is an lvalue, not an xvalue. There's no rvalue reference in this code.

Comment: @T.C. I think you're confusing terms. The name "rvalue reference" names a _type_; it does not have anything to do with the value category of the reference. And, quite clearly, in `A const& ref = foo()` the initializer is an rvalue expression (with type "[lvalue] reference to `A`"). Where would you say there is an lvalue expression? And where did I claim that there was an rvalue reference type (`A&&`)?

Comment: Well, you called it an xvalue, and "An xvalue is the result of certain kinds of expressions involving rvalue references (8.3.2)." An expression having the type `lvalue reference to A` is an lvalue expression. It's even called out in the bullet right above the bullet you cited - "As another example, the result of calling a function whose return type is an lvalue reference is an lvalue."

Comment: @T.C. You _are_ correct actually in that `foo()` is an lvalue (whoops in my previous comment) but in my answer (three years ago!) I am talking about the place where the reference is initialised. Even there, you're right to say that there are no xvalue expressions in the code. It's been so long now that I don't really know what's going on here now. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my incomplete and possible insufficient view on the matter:

The only thing special about references is that *at initialization time* they must refer to a valid object. If the object later stops existing, using the reference is UB, and so is initializing another reference to the now-defunct reference.

The following much simpler example provides exactly the same dilemma as your question, I think:

```
std::reference_wrapper<T> r;

{
    T t;
    r = std::ref(t);
}

// #1
```

At #1, the reference inside `r` is no longer valid, but the program is fine. Just don't *read* `r`.

In your example, line #1 is fine, and line #2 isn't -- that is because the original line #2 calls `A::A(A const &)` with argument `foo()`, and as discussed, this fails to initialize the function argument variable with a *valid* reference, and so would your edited version `A const & a = foo();`.

Comment: +1: I agree completely (though it's a shame there's nothing making this explicit in _el standard_, and I sort of wish that just _having_ the invalid reference were UB).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, think about it that way - if it had all been written with pointers, there wouldn't even be any confusion. I suppose all we need now is a phrase in the standard that says "using a reference to a non-existing object is UB", or something of the sort, parallel to the statement about dereferencing pointers.

Comment: But you can't even copy invalid pointers, can you? I mean, strictly speaking.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Hm, you may be right - the only valid pointer values are those that *are* addresses of existing objects (or one past). So perhaps the situation is precisely the same for pointers as it is for references.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It does match the speculative feeling I have about this issue,but still It doesn't satisfy my curiosity of what the Standard says about this.UB for such boundary conditions with pointers/references are not clearly specified in the Standard is the lingering feeling I have.Not that this stops me from writing any code but just I wonder since standard doesn't specify it(We haven't been able to find it yet) then how do compilers interpret these rules.

Comment: @Als: I don't think it's that nebulous: If a pointer's value is not the address-of a live object, you cannot use it, simple as that. Similarly, I would say that if a reference's address-of isn't the address-of a live object, you have the same situation.

Comment: @KerrekSB: As Tomalak already pointed out and I agree that,You can still copy invalid pointers without invoking UB.

Comment: @Als: I was wondering about that last one... while *practically* of course you can copy any pointer to heart's content, I'm not sure what the standard says about that - can you initialize an object to an invalid value?

Comment: @Als: Unfortunately it's very difficult to provide citations for this. The semantics here are just a combination of everything the standard says, along with everything that it _doesn't_ say. Also, for what it's worth, it doesn't seem terribly explicit on the matter in either case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I agree. The standard tells you what a valid pointer is. It doesn't say that everything that it doesn't declare as valid is invalid, and rightly so.

Comment: The rules about lvalue/rvalue conversions and a bunch of crap in 3.8 come close to something we can rationalise about.

Comment: What about section 8.3.2/4 (from C++03), "... A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function. ..." Can it be argued that the returned `A&` would be associated with an invalid object at the time that `ref` is initialized (which presumably would be after foo has returned and the object `A&` refers to has been destroyed)?

Comment: I agree with your and @LightnessRacesinOrbit comments that it is hard to cite a straight reference from the Standard for this and hence the Q.I am going to let this Q stay open and wait to see if some answers come by.

Comment: @Als: I've done the same myself for questions of similar format. Good luck!

Comment: @DRH: Oh, that'd probably do it... It *is* a new reference, after all... (there are two references here!)

Answer (score 0):

I would say #3. Alone, #2 doesn't actually do anything even though the referenced object is already out of scope. This isn't really a standards-related issue because it is the result of two mistakes made in succession:

1. Returning a reference to an out-of-scope object followed by
2. Use of a reference.

Either in isolation has defined behavior. Whether the standard has anything to say regarding use of references to objects beyond the end of their lifetime is another matter.

Comment: There is no authority in this answer. It's mere unfounded speculation!

Comment: @Lightness: Nor did I claim any!

Comment: @JMcF: Please no speculations,the Q is clear enough so I just expect a clear answer.I wouldn't ask the Q If i was expecting speculations because even I can speculate because doing that needs no real evidence  .

Comment: @Als: Apologies for any misunderstanding, but it was not clear to me. You said: "To be clear at what exact statement(#1 or #2 or #3) does code sample below exhibits an Undefined Behavior" and I answered that question. You also said "an ideal answer would cite an reference" but you did not say that only ideal answers were allowed.

Comment: @JMcF: By that logic, I could write an answer that says "LOL BALLOONS! Balloons would be better here" which would be equally valid. After all, he didn't _ask_ for facts...

Comment: @Als: You could but it wouldn't and as I quoted, he did. Regardless, I will try to elaborate in my answer.

Comment: I see no such quotation in any of your posts. This is better now, though.