# Is it safe to cast pointer to integer, increment that integer, and cast back?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, reinterpret-cast, pointer-conversion

Suppose I have a valid pointer `p0`:

```
T a[10];
T* p0 = &a[0];
```

I know that I can safely round-trip-cast it like this:

```
reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p0)) == p0;
```

But is it safe to do the following?

```
T* p1 = reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p0) + sizeof(T));
```

i.e. can I be sure that there is no UB and that `p1 == &a[1]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "can I be sure that there is no unsigned byte"? *Where*?

Comment: @theV0ID UB is a popular acronym in C++ world for Undefined Behavior.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that'll fail on word-addressed systems, where incrementing an address by `n` makes it point `n*wordsize` bytes further.

Comment: @theV0ID: Undefined behavior, not unsigned byte.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624472/can-stduintptr-t-be-used-to-avoid-undefined-behavior-of-out-of-bounds-pointer

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks a lot for this witty input.

Comment: @theV0ID: Back atcha :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is implementation-defined behaviour. Your compiler should document whether or not pointer arithmetic is equivalent to integer arithmetic on the converted numeric values of pointers. That should be the case on modern computers with a "flat" byte-addressed memory space; but it's not guaranteed to work portably on all platforms.

Using `char*` rather than `uintptr_t` will work portably, as long as you stay within the array and ensure the pointer is correctly aligned for `T` before converting back.