# Weird behavior of ">=" operator when comparing two pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement

I'm trying to compare numerical values of two pointers with ">=" operator but instead of comparing them it adds some random values to the first.

```
void obj::Loader::calculate_size(const char* start_ptr, const char* end_ptr, atomic_long& v, atomic_long& vt, atomic_long& vn, atomic_long& f) {
    while (start_ptr >= end_ptr) {
        if (*start_ptr == 'v') {
            start_ptr++;
            if (*start_ptr == ' ') {
                v++;
                start_ptr += 27;
            }
            else if (*start_ptr == 't') {
                vt++;
                start_ptr += 18;
            }
            else if (*start_ptr == 'n') {
                vn++;
                start_ptr += 21;
            }
        }
        else if (*start_ptr == 'f') {
            start_ptr++;
            if (*start_ptr == ' ') {
                f += 3;
                start_ptr += 17;
            }
        }
        start_ptr++;
    }
}
```

This function is supposed to count all instances of these letters in a part of a memory-mapped file (from "start_ptr" to "end_ptr"). Knowing the minimal length at certain portions of the file I decided to increment the "start_ptr" by more than one sometimes but by doing that I can't rely on "!=" operator to stop the loop.

The problem is ">=" doesn't really work as it would on integers and it just crashes the whole thing. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Did you mean to write `<=` instead of `>=`? The loop never stops otherwise (pointer arithmetic issues aside).

Comment: Regarding pointer arithmetic: Although it is unlikely that this will cause you problems, increasing the pointer the way you are doing [may technically be undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473573/why-is-out-of-bounds-pointer-arithmetic-undefined-behaviour).

Comment: @uneven_mark You mean the loop never starts

Comment: @M.M Either or.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the loop condition is `start_ptr >= end_ptr`, and considering that the loop body only ever increments `start_ptr`, if the loop is ever entered, then `start_ptr` can never become smaller than `end_ptr` and therefore the loop is infinite. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

It would be rather unconventional for "start" to be after the end, so I suspect that this is a mistake in the logic.

Comment: Oh. Right. I typed it in reverse. I should probably get some sleep, thank you. Please someone delete this o.o

Comment: The question can be closed as typo, which is nearly as good as deleting

Answer (score 1):

The comparison looks to be wrong to me:  instead of

```
while (start_ptr >= end_ptr) {
    // [...]
    start_ptr++;
}
```

I would expect the natural condition to be:

```
while (start_ptr < end_ptr) {
    // [...]
    start_ptr++;
}
```

I suspect the crash in your program is not due to the pointer comparison directly, but is a side effect of something unexpected that happens when the loop is not entered.