# Write code to reverse a C-style string in place

Tags: c, string

I know this question has been asked many times before, but I just have a few questions about my code below.

So the code below doesn't work because in my while loop I have `str != end` instead of `str < end`. Why does it have to be `str < end`? I'm confused because it seems like the condition `str != end` should work the same way, since the pointers will eventually be pointing at the same position.

My second question is why we have to do `while(*end){end++;}` instead of `while(end){end++}`. Isn't the pointer invalid when we move past the length of end anyway? What is `while(end){end++}` doing if it's not correct?

My last question is that in other variations of this code, I've seen a condition added to the top of this function that says `if(!(*str)){return;}`. Is this necessary? My code seems to handle the empty string fine without this. Also, similar to `*end` vs `end`, why do we have to do `!(*str)` instead of `!(str)`?

```
   void reverse(char *str){
       char *end = str;
       while(*end){
          end++;
       }
       end--;

       while(str != end){
          char tmp = *str;
          *str = *end;
          *end = tmp;
          str++; end--;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Try reverse (""). Kaboom!

Comment: And don't use the ! operator when == 0 or == NULL would be more appropriate. It's confusing. Mostly to yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You increment `str` *and* decrement `end` at the same time (`str++; end--;`). So it's possible for them to hop over each other and never be equal when you come to compare them.

In your current implementation, if an empty string is passed (`*str==0`) then you *still* unconditionally decrement `end` (`end--`, 5th line of function).  So now it looks like `str` *starts out* larger than `end` which is bad news if `str!=end` is the conditional in your loop (I say "looks like" because, as [pointed out by Cornstalks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606545/write-code-to-reverse-a-c-style-string-in-place/27607302#27607302), it's actually undefined behaviour—under some circumstances the compiler might for example adjust `end` so that points *too far ahead* of `str`).  In any event, it's even worse news as soon as you dereference `end`, because you're likely messing with unallocated memory.

As for your question about `!(*str)` :   if `*str==0`  that means that the string is empty, whereas if `str==0` that means the calling function has passed you a NULL string pointer. You should check for both eventualities—specifically, to avoid blowing up the universe, check whether the pointer is NULL first, *before* you attempt to dereference it.

Comment: Good job at noticing that `if(!(*str)){return;}` is necessary to avoid invalidly decrementing `end`. Heck, it's actually undefined behavior to decrement `end` to point to an invalid memory location (in this case, 1-past the start of the string).

Comment: No! [It's undefined behavior even if you don't dereference it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27607302/1287251)

Comment: Fair enough. Edited accordingly.  Though I reserve the right to define "bad news" as I see fit to validate whatever point I'm making.  Also a disclaimer:  de-referencing NULL is not guaranteed to blow up the universe (nor is it guaranteed not to).

Answer (score 1):

1. `Why does it have to be str < end?`

Consider what happens for strings with an even number of characters, e.g. "abcdef".

2. `why we have to do while(*end){end++;} instead of while(end){end++}.`

You're looking for the null byte terminating the string, i.e. when the pointer `end` points to a null byte. Using the latter version which make the loop terminate only when the pointer points to address zero.

3. `I've seen a condition added to the top of this function that says if(!(*str)){return;}. Is this necessary?`

<del>No</del>**Yes!** As the other answers correctly pointed out, the check avoids that `--end;` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `str < end` because you do `str++; end--;`. What happens if end is exactly above str and you do `str++; end--;`? After that str will be exactly above end and they will differ but you don't want to continue your loop.

end is allways a pointer. It might point to some valid memory or it might point somewhere which will give you a segfault if you try to access that memory. Increasing a pointer will only make it point to a higher address. It will not become NULL just because the address is invalid. That is why you have to look at `*end` to find the end of your null terminated string.

With your current code it does not seem necessary to have the check `if(!(*str)){return;}` as empty strings are catched by the fact that str and end becomes the same. However, it might be a good idea to add `if(!str){return;}` to avoid getting a segfault if someone calls your function with a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

1. The condition `str != end` will give you adequate results only if your string has an odd number of characters. Otherwise it is well possible that you have the following sequence:

   `str 0 1 2`

   `end 3 2 1`

   At this point, `str != end` is still true, although your pointers already passed the middle of the string.
2. `while(end)` doesn't check if the pointer is valid in the sense that it is pointing to a value you previously assigned to that memory address. It only checks if `end` is different from `NULL`.
3. This is not technically necessary, but it ensures that you exit the function immediately if the string is empty, without doing any additional work.

   **Edit:** As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27607302/1387126) by Cornstalks, it *is* necessary to check this.

Comment: The `if(!(*str)){return;}` check is still necessary. [See jez's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27606632/1287251).

Comment: It's *better* to check this, no doubt, but this is not critically necessary, it just makes the code more efficient. Concerning checking if `str` is a null-pointer, this may or may not be necessary depending on the context, but this was not part of the question anyway.

Comment: No, it is necessary. Without it, `end--;` will always (unconditionally) be executed. This means that 1) `end` will be less than `str` now, and 2) undefined behavior will be invoked because the pointer has been decremented outside of its valid range.

Comment: But if the second while loop is implemented correctly with `while(str < end)` then it's perfectly fine if `end` is less than `str` or lies outside of string bounds, the second while loop will not be entered and the function will return immediately thereafter.

Comment: [You're ignoring the fact that decrementing end to outside of the valid range is undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27607302/1287251)

Answer (score 1):

I want to specifically answer the question regarding whether `if(!(*str)){return;}` is necessary.

**Yes, it is absolutely necessary with your current code**.

Without it, `end--` will be executed. This means that `end` will be decremented outside of the valid range `[str, str + strlen(str) + 1]` (you can increment a pointer one-past the end of its memory block, but you can't dereference it).

**[Doing so is actually undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838855/is-storing-an-invalid-pointer-automatically-undefined-behavior)**. A pointer outside if a valid memory range is undefined behavior, even if you don't dereference it.

For example, if your computer is using a [segmented memory model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model), then your comparison `(str < end)` might still be true, even if you have an empty string and you decremented `end` (in this case, `end` could have wrapped around and `str < end` is still true).

Consider, for example, a `aaaa:bbbb` segmented memory model. `aaaa` is the segment, `bbbb` is the offset within the segment. If `str` is a pointer to `1234:0000`, and you decrement it, it could be a new value `1234:ffff`. Why didn't the segment decrement? Because the compiler knows you can't jump segments; a pointer can only point to data within the current segment. So when doing pointer arithmetic, it only modifies the offset (the lower two bytes) of the pointer. Now, `str < end` is still true, and the code will continue and wreck havoc.

Comment: You mean "If `end` is a pointer to `1234:0000`"? Ok, I see now.

Comment: Yes, I mean if `str` is `1234:0000` (and, because of the assignment `end = str`, then `end` is `1234:0000` as well, which could get wrapped around to `1234:ffff` with the decrement).

Comment: Isn't that the same reason to check whether `str` is a null pointer? Dereferencing a null pointer in `while (*end)` is undefined behavior either, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you'd either want to check for a null pointer to avoid a dereference, or you could just make it part of the function's contract that the argument shall not be null (for example, `strlen` doesn't check if the pointer is null, because the function contract is that you shall not pass it a null pointer).

Answer (score 0):

> it seems like the condition `str != end` should work the same way, since the pointers will eventually be pointing at the same position.

That depends on whether the string has an even or an odd number of characters. In the former case, the `str` and `end` pointers will move *past* each other and will never be equal.

> What is `while(end){end++}` doing if it's not correct?

This is checking whether `end` is `NULL`, and you are not setting `end` to `NULL`.

Comment: So "end" is not NULL when it reaches the null-terminating character?

Comment: @BobJohn: Right (but `*end` is `0`).

Comment: OK. That makes sense. Do you have any comments about whether I need if(!(*str)) and why?