# Can pointer point to itself memory address in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

In the following code, a pointer points to its own memory address.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    void * ptr;
    ptr = &ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

**Would it make sense, if the pointer was able to point to its own memory address?**

Comment: What would you expect an error or warning to say?  That is, what is the (even potential) problem here?

Comment: I guess this falls into the class of 'weird, but if you insist on doing it, there is no problem'.

Answer (score 7):

No, it doesn't make sense.
If you can find variable ptr, you can just do &ptr.
It will give you the same results as the contents of ptr.

Moreover since ptr only tells something about itself, it's useless anyhow. It doesn't provide any info meaningful to the rest of your program.

**Come to think of it, there's one exception. You could use the case where ptr == &ptr as a kind of special value, like NULL. So, in that case I would consider it useful.**

The fun of it is that in that case the value &ptr makes sense as a special value precisely while it doesn't make sense as the address of something, just like NULL.

Comment: Your answer is becoming more and [*Cicero*ian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicero) answer .... ;-) Or [was it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicero) Socrates or Plato?

Comment: Pitty that you can't do the comparison `ptr == &ptr` without a cast in virtually all cases as the types will differ.

Comment: Yes, I'd write a template function with a ref param for that... But it isn't efficient. On the other hand, having not one but two special values is in itself remarkable.

Comment: In what way does this make less sense than, say, 'ptr = ptr'?

Comment: @ScottHunter: I think your example cannot be compared as  `void * ptr = ptr;` isn`t legal.

Comment: @ScottHunter: In case ptr is an object with an overloaded = operator with side effects (joke).

Comment: @alk: If C claims to have any even minimally viable type system, `ptr = ptr` should not be illegal.

Comment: @scotthunter: You are right, it's not illegal. Still, it does provoke the infamous Undefined Behaviour, which may be considered even worth.

Comment: How on earth can `ptr = ptr` provoke Undefined Behavior (without relying on previously Undefined Behavior, it which case the assignment isn't doing the provoking)?  I'm sorry, but if that isn't well defined, C should just pack it in.

Comment: @ScottHunter: `void * ptr = ptr;` tries to set `ptr` to the value of what is read from the (yet still) uninitialised variable `ptr`. Reading an uninitialised variable is UB. Same for `int a = a;` or alike, BTW.

Comment: @alk: `void* ptr = ptr;` won't even *compile*, as `ptr` hasn't been defined yet, so can't be used as an initializer; *you* were tho one to add `void *`; I was just referring to assigning a variable to itself.

Comment: @ScottHunter: ``void * ptr = ptr;`` will compile. My last comment holds as well for: `void * ptr; ptr = ptr;` For the latter GCC issues: "*warning: ‘ptr’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]*"

Answer (score 5):

> Pointer point to its own memory address

It's legal.

Whether it "*makes sense*" 100%ly depends on the context and though "*is primarily option based*".

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense as it is legal C language assignment. Another question is what for. IMO this is just the scholastic consideration without any practical use.

Comment: Not everything that's legal makes sense... I can e.g. glue wallpaper on my car.

Comment: Agree with @PeterJ

Comment: @PeterJ I read it, but "making sense" for me means "having a purpose".

Comment: Tho words taken out of the full statement is called a manipulation. I wrote it clearly that it does not have any practical use

Comment: Don't take it so seriously, your meaning was perfectly clear and alright! I am just nitpicking, because I still didn't have my breakfast!

Comment: As said, just nitpicking.

Answer (score -3):

Another aspect that has not been mentioned yet, is that it goes against strict typing.
If `ptr`is of type `void *`, then `&ptr` is of type `void **` and should not be assigned to `ptr` due to the type mismatch (`void *`vs. `void **`).
However C and C++ are generally very lax when it comes to pointer types, whenever one assigns to a `void *`, because a `void *` is supposed to be able to point to just about anything.
But suppose you actually want to dereference `ptr` properly, you would (after your assignment) have to do it like

`*(void **)ptr = ...`

assuming you actually want to dereference it at some point.

Comment: "*that it goes against strict typing.*" in C there is no such rule for `void`-pointers. In C casting to/from a `void`-pointer from/to any other pointer type is legal. In C+ it is not.

Comment: Actually that is included in my post, but not adhering strict typing is still bad style, hence I thought it worth to mention.