# Difference between (int *)p and &p

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

what is the difference between the statements
`int *p = (int*) i; and int *q=&i;`

Here is whole program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
     int i;
     int *p = (int*) i; 
     printf("\n p is %d ",p);
     int *q = &i;
     printf("\n q is %d ",q);
     return 0;
 }
```

the output obtained is 
 `p is 22092 
 q is 1002476148`

 i think here both p and q are storing the address of i , but  they are showing different values, can somebody explain why it is happenning?

Comment: so if (int *) i is returning the value in i then what is the actual use of this (int *), like where it is used

Comment: since `i` is a default initialized, it will contain random value, which is being stored to pointer `p` too, that is why you are getting two values.

Answer (score 2):

First: pointers must be cast to `(void*)` and printed with `%p`. `%d` prints an `int` in base 10. That is,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    int *p = (int*) i; 
    printf("\n p is %p ", (void*)p);
    int *q = &i;
    printf("\n q is %p ", (void*)q);
}
```

Now let's try to compile the program with these changes: only 2 errors:

```
% gcc ptr.c -Wall -Wextra
ptr.c: In function ‘main’:
ptr.c:5:14: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     int *p = (int*) i;
              ^
ptr.c:5:14: warning: ‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     int *p = (int*) i;
              ^~~~~~~~
```

Both pertanining to the `int *p = (int*) i;`; the second says that the value of `i` is used but we didn't set any value to `i` (this causes *undefined behaviour*) and the other that we're trying to convert an integer to a pointer, and the integer doesn't have the same amount of bits as a pointer has on this platform.

I.e.

```
int *q = &i;
```

initializes pointer to int `q` with the address of variable `i`, whereas

```
int *p = (int*) i;
```

interprets the garbage value contained in `i`, in an implementation-defined manner, as an address, and initializes `p` with that.

Not quite equal.

Comment: so insted of pthread_create(&philosopher[i],NULL,(void *)process,(int *)i );
can i use pthread_create(&philosopher[i],NULL,process,i ); instead

Comment: @AdarshD for `pthread_create`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19236285/918959

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
int *p = (int*) i; /* i is not initialized */
```

pointer `p` gets assigned with value of `i` which is some garbage data & tries to cast some junk data to `int*` type and assigned to `p`. If you tries to dereference `p` it gives **segmentation fault** & causes **undefined behavior**.

And Here

```
int *q = &i;
```

pointer `q` is assigned with valid address.

Also while printing pointer variable use `%p` instead of `%d` format specifier for e.g

```
 printf("\n q is %p ",(void*)q);
```

About assigning *integer values* to a *pointer* like `int *p = (int*) i` , **C standard** says

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> (5) An **integer** may be converted to **any pointer type**. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is **implementation-defined**, might
>   not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the
>   referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

Comment: Read [Can I assign any integer value to a pointer variable directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766142/can-i-assign-any-integer-value-to-a-pointer-variable-directly).

Answer (score 0):

According to the C standard ISO/IEC 9899:2011, subclause 6.3.2.3:

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

It follows that when you cast `i` to `pointer-to-int` type, what it holds is generally undefined.