# Is it undefined behavior to access the object representation of a pointer through a char*?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing

I know this is weird question, but just bad curious.

```
char* ptr = 0;
strcpy( (char*) &ptr, "UB?");
```

This code means 'I will use the memory of ptr as a char array.'
I think 'it's absolutely UB', but someone says 'it's not UB until you dereference'.
It is not UB? How can this awful code not be UB?

Comment: IMO, it's not UB (assuming `sizeof(char *) >= 7`), but it's not remotely useful.  You can't use the pointer as a pointer afterwards.  You could use it as a string with the bludgeoning cast repeated, but bludgeoning casts like that are inherently dubious!

Comment: Well, for one thing, that will write out of bounds if `sizeof ptr < 8`

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838855/is-storing-an-invalid-pointer-automatically-undefined-behavior

Comment: I don't know if it's the same. That's why you don't ask multiple questions in the same Question. I can't answer your question until it's fixed, because I don't know which of the two questions you're asking. Do edit.

Comment: As @Barmar notes about the size of pointers, I suggest modifying the question to use a shorter string. `strcpy( (char*) &ptr, "me?");` would work even on a system with 32-bit pointers.

Comment: You could even use `strncpy` passing the size of `char *` to avoid overwriting the limits of the pointer's memory and invoking UB that way.

Comment: @Chris There are systems where `sizeof(char*)` is 2 (e.g. MS-DOS memory models with *near* pointers), so you could only copy a 1-character string plus null terminator into a `char *` on such systems.

Comment: It's just a bad idea all the way around. You can cram whatever you want into the 8-bytes of storage, but that is beside the point. If 1000 lines lines later in your code, you have `char str[32];` and then someone attempts `strcpy (str, ptr);` really bad things will happen. That is were UB will creep (or crash) back into your code as you attempt to access the "non"-address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can a char\* alias with any object pointer, but not the other way around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848188/why-can-a-char-alias-with-any-object-pointer-but-not-the-other-way-around)

Comment: @JanSchultke Not a great duplicate since every single answer fails to back up the claims with sources, as appropriate for "language lawyer" questions.

Comment: And to "answer" the question, I think this should be a strictly conforming C program printing "hello world": https://godbolt.org/z/h1sEKxPjr  :) Doesn't everyone implement hello world like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C17 §6.5 paragraph 6 includes:

> The *effective type* of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if any. *[...]*

The effective type of the object denoted by `ptr` is `char *`.

Paragraph 7 includes:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

The object denoted by `ptr` is having its stored value accessed by an lvalue expression of character type (via the `strcpy` function which interprets characters as if they had type `unsigned char`). This is not UB.

Comment: Also relevant (and fully in sync with the "strict aliasing" rules) is 6.3.2.3 §7 "When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object." This guarantees that not only the lvalue access is ok as per 6.5, but also that it is ok to iterate through the bytes of a character pointer's representation, by using another `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

How could it be UB when this is legal (albeit horrible)?

```
union {
    char arr[4];
    char *ptr;
} trouble;

strcpy( trouble.arr, "UB?" );
```

Comment: This begs for a `feeling_lucky` function that deferences the pointer.

Comment: The provenance of pointers sometimes matters in C.  The fact that your similar, union-based example is well-defined has little bearing on the case presented in the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm sorry, I don't understand "sometimes matters". In my experience, the address of a pointer is the address of a pointer. Please explain...

Comment: For example, C does not define the behavior of using a pointer derived from an array identifier to access past the end of the array, even if it is well defined what lies immediately after the end of the array.  For another example, accessing an object through a `restrict`-qualified pointer can make modifications to the same object through other pointers have undefined behavior.  Neither of those cases applies to your example, but the point is that you are not justified in assuming that the value of the pointer is the only concern with respect to the definedness of the behavior.

Comment: The behavior of the OP's code *is* well defined, to be sure, but the reasoning presented in this answer is nonsense.  The two cases are not meaningfully analogous.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The OP defined and used the memory of a pointer variable (without any `restrict` qualifiers.) This example defines and uses the memory of a pointer as a member of a union variable (without any `restrict` qualifiers.) The two are equivalent. Imagining alternate (but valid) scenarios helps no-one.

Comment: PS: No one who knows what they are doing would use a pointer to "_access past the end of the array_" Besides, there's no suggestion of dereferencing the pointer in this question or this answer... Given that the value stored in those bytes has been "fiddled", dereferencing **would** invoke UB (as you know.)

Comment: I am not presenting alternate scenarios.  I am presenting examples demonstrating, as you requested, that the provenance of a pointer (can) make a difference in C.  But that was always a side comment.  The main point is that the reason your example is valid is different from the reason the OP's is valid.  The two cases are not analogous in that sense.  The validity of one does not speak to the validity of the other.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Both examples treat the address of a pointer as if it were the address of an array of characters. I must be thick because I do not see why they are not analogous. I'd welcome an explanation of "is different from the reason..."

Comment: The OP's case is valid because the strict aliasing rule allows access to an object of any type via an lvalue of character type.  Your case is valid because one can write to any (non-`const`) member of a union, and the storage of all members of the same union overlaps.  Your example can be generalized to access via non-character types.  The OP's cannot, but the analogy you're drawing can easily be construed to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I get your point, now... Thank you... However, that this example's answer accesses those bytes via `char arr[]`, (not some other datatype), kinda makes it analogous, no? Some days it's better to not stick one's hand up... I'm done if you are...

Comment: This is a bad example, because GCC developers actually [refused to implement](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65892) this kind of SA exception for union members used as function arguments. So your code would work on GCC solely because `char *` is allowed to alias anything, not because of the union.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: What's funny is that Tim Rensch seems willfully ignorant of the purpose of the "One Special Guarantee": to allow functions that may be passed pointers to a variety of structure types that share a Common Initial Sequence to treat all such types interchangeably when accessing members of the CIS.

Answer (score 0):

The Standard does not recognize any limitation on such constructs, provided the representation of the pointer is large enough to accommodate the string, but the CompCertC dialect requires that any storage which is used to hold data pointers must be accessed exclusively using lvalues of data-pointer types.  Unlike the C Standard, it would allow `void**` to be used as a "pointer to any data pointer" type for purposes of accessing storage that is used to hold any data pointer, but it does not allow the use of `unsigned char*` or other similar types for such purposes.

I am unaware of any formally-specified dialect other than CompCertC that would not allow manipulation of pointer representations via `unsigned char*` or similar types.