# Pointing to before the beginning of the array in a for loop

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Consider the following C code:

```
for (data_object_t *first = get_first(dev),
                   *last  = first + get_num_of_data_objects(dev) - 1,
                   *curr  = first;
                    curr <= last;
                    curr++) {
        // process *curr
    }
```

Assume that `get_first()` returns a pointer to an object sitting within some big array of `data_object_t`'s, and that `get_num_of_data_objects()` never returns a value that will cause out of bound access.

My question is specifically about the case where `get_num_of_data_objects()` returns 0.
In this case, `last` will be `first - 1`, so I'd expect the loop to simply be skipped (because `curr <= last` evaluates to false right from the start), but what was bothering me is the potential for having `last` pointing to **before** the beginning of the array, which made me wonder - even if it's not being dereferenced:
Is this a bad practice?
Is there a potential for undefined behavior here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing an invalid pointer automatically undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838855/is-storing-an-invalid-pointer-automatically-undefined-behavior)

Comment: It is implicit in your question that `get_first(dev)` points to the **first** element of an array, but this is not explicitly stated. For clarity, you should state this is the case you are concerned about, as, in other cases when `get_first(dev)` returns a pointer to some element after the first, calculating `first - 1` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was about to comment the same. In particular, this method is occasionally used to enable indexing arrays with negative indices. K&R has a nice section on this, which the OP might want to read if they haven't already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `first` points to the start of an array, `first - 1` attempts to create a pointer to before the beginning of the array. In this situation, the behaviour of `first - 1` is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The rules regarding pointer addition and subtraction are spelled out in section 6.5.6p8 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted
> from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
> pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
> is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
> original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
> resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
> In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an
> array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N
> (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and
> i−n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if
> the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the
> expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object,
> and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array
> object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
> object. **If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
> of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
> object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
> behavior is undefined.** If the result points one past the last element
> of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary *
> operator that is evaluated.

These rules do not allow for creating a pointer to before the beginning of an array.

What they do allow for however is to have a pointer to one element past the end of the array (although it can't be dereferenced).  So you can use that to modify your loop as follows:

```
for (data_object_t *first = get_first(dev),
                   *last  = first + get_num_of_data_objects(dev),
                   *curr  = first;
                    curr < last;
                    curr++) {
        // process *curr
    }
```

Comment: Actually, it won't be an undefined behavior as long as you don't dereference it.
As I explained in my answer, pointers have invalid addresses the whole time and that's just part of C programming.

Undefined behavior happens only when you dereference it, which is not the case in this code.

Comment: @Ágatha No, the standard is specifically stating that it is undefined behavior to have a pointer arithmetic resulting in such a pointer. See https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8

Comment: @Ágatha: Regarding addition of an integer to or subtraction of an integer from a pointer, C 2018 6.5.6 8 says “… If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined…” Since `first - 1` does not produce a result that points to an element of the same array object that `first` points to, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Ágatha - We are now used to flat address spaces, but not long ago (well...) we used segmented memory, where the address before an array might not exist.

Comment: I thank the users who pointed me to the standard and, well, if the standard says it's undefined then it's undefined. I deleted my answer and corrected myself.

@BoP I am aware of that. However, my point WAS (incorrectly) that storing an invalid address wouldn't be a problem per se, the problem would be when you dereference it. For instance, an unitialized pointer or a pointer initialized as NULL both might point to invalid locations. Of course it's a bad practice to have memory garbage pointer, but it's not a problem until you try to access the pointed memory region.