# How to use Boost's intrusive_ptr effectively?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, boost, smart-pointers

### Manual Unref

I have an issue with Boost's intrusive pointer. It's [boolean conversion operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html#conversions) checks `x.get() != 0`. However, the code below fails at the marked point. Why is this the case?

I am guessing that I may have to do with the fact that [`delete` does not set a pointer to `0`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5002055/1170277) (or `nullptr`). If that's not the case, how could I use the intrusive pointer effectively? I would like to be able to use an intrusive pointer like a regular pointer, e.g., in an expression `x && x->foo()`, but this artefact seems to preclude it.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>

struct T
{
    T() : count(0u) { }

    size_t ref_count()
    {
        return count;
    }

    std::atomic_size_t count;
};

void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(T* p)
{
    ++p->count;
}

void intrusive_ptr_release(T* p)
{
    if (--p->count == 0u)
        delete p;
}

int main()
{
    boost::intrusive_ptr<T> x;
    x = new T;
    assert(x->ref_count() == 1);

    auto raw = x.get();
    intrusive_ptr_add_ref(raw);
    intrusive_ptr_add_ref(raw);
    assert(x->ref_count() == 3);

    intrusive_ptr_release(raw);
    intrusive_ptr_release(raw);
    assert(x->ref_count() == 1);

    intrusive_ptr_release(raw); // Destroys T, ref_count() == 0.
    assert(! x); // Fails.

    return 0;
}
```

(Architecture: Darwin 10.7, tested compilers g++ 4.7 and 4.6 with `-std=c++11`)

### Reference-to-Pointer

After weeding through the source code of `intrusive_ptr<T>`, I found that there is only one call to `intrusive_ptr_release` in the destructor:

```
~intrusive_ptr()
{
    if( px != 0 ) intrusive_ptr_release( px );
}
```

Since the argument `px` of type `T*` is an lvalue, it should be possible to set it to zero by slightly changing the function signature of `intrusive_ptr_release`:

```
inline void intrusive_ptr_release(T*& p)
{
    if (--p->count == 0u)
    {
        delete p;
        p = 0;
    }
}
```

Intuitively, this pointer reference-to-pointer parameter should assign the lvalue of `p` in the calling context to 0. Bjarne also [mentions this idiom](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#delete-zero). However, the assertion still fails at the marked line, leaving me clueless this time.

### Example Usage

The reason why I am ref'ing and unref'ing the pointer manually is that I have to work with the raw pointer for a while when passing it to a C API. This means I have to ref it before passing it to the C API in order to prevent destruction, and recreate an intrusive pointer from the raw pointer when I get it back. Here is an example:

```
void f()
{
    intrusive_ptr<T> x = new T;
    auto raw = x.get();
    intrusive_ptr_add_ref(raw);
    api_in(raw);
}

void g()
{
    T* raw = api_out();
    intrusive_ptr<T> y(raw, false);
    h(y);
}
```

Here, the second parameter in the construction of `y` in `g()` avoids a ref when getting the pointer back from the C API, which compensates for the manual ref in `f()`.

I realized that manually unreffing an intrusive pointer can lead to unexpected behavior, whereas this usage appears to be fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question is: Why do you expect x to convert to false at the end? You're messing with the ref counter in unexpected ways! You're decreasing it to zero *even though* there is still an `intrusive_ptr` — x — that points to the object. That's not how it works. The ref counter is supposed to be at least as great as the number of `intrusive_ptr` objects that point to the ref counted object — otherwise it would not be a ref counter, would it?

Comment: Put in other words: Intrusive pointers in general, and `intrusive_ptr` in particular (and also Microsoft COM pointers), work correctly when all of its users obey **ownership semantics with its pointers**, whether these pointers are C++ templates or raw C pointer. **Ownership semantics** requires that any **refcount-changing event only occur via a pointer (raw or smart) under the condition that ownership by that pointer is ascertained**. (In layman terms, you don't meddle what you don't own.) In OP's code sample, the `(intrusive_ptr) x` is the one which has certain ownership of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation on `intrusive_ptr` I see there is no connection between "destroying" the object, using its own terminology, and the pointer being 0. So, if you want to use the `x && x->foo()` idiom, your `intrusive_ptr_release` function should set the pointer to `0` too.

I can see the design decision here in `intrusive_ptr`. When `intrusive_ptr_release` gets called, only destruction should be performed, without including any other behavior than that provided by `delete`, so if you also want to put the pointer to `0` to support the idiom, you have to do it in your code for that function, but `intrusive_ptr` itself does not force you to include more restrictions than `delete` itself: that is, it doesn't force you to reset the pointer to `0`.

Comment: I understand the functions `intrusive_ptr_add_ref` and `intrusive_ptr_release` to take a raw pointer rather than an `intrusive_ptr`. This would not allow for setting the private `intrusive_ptr` member `px` to `0`, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. The pointer you get in the function is copied by value, so you cannot modify it. I guess then that this technique can be used as a one-time wrapper of directly received values, to perform (locally, inside a function) a reference counted work with the pointer.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your last comment? I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Perhaps I addressed what you mean with my question edit.

Comment: Yes, I was about to suggest the change to a `T*&`, but I'm not sure if this is allowed by the contract of `intrusive_ptr`. Doing that function in your edit you get the behavior you expect, so I guess it is "practically right".