# Object does not point to NULL after deleting

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nullptr

I have a `Node` class. The members are an `int id`, and a pointer to the next node: `Node* next`. I implemented the constructor and destructor as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Node
{
public:
  int id;
  Node *next;
  Node() : id(0), next(nullptr) {}
  explicit Node(int id) : id(id), next(nullptr) {}

  ~Node() {
    std::cout << (*this) << " destructed \n";
    delete next;
    next = nullptr;
  }

  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Node &node) {
    os << "Node(" << node.id << ")";
    return os;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Node *node0;
  Node *node1;
  node0 = new Node(0);
  node1 = new Node(1);
  node0->next = node1;

  delete node0; // outputs Node(0) destructed\nNode(1) destructed
  node0 = nullptr;
  std::cout << (nullptr == node0) << '\n'; // outputs 1
  std::cout << (nullptr == node1) << '\n'; // outputs 0
  std::cout << *node1 << " \n"; // outputs Node(8430)
  return 0;
}
```

I thought `node1` should already point to `nullptr` since when calling the destructor for `node0`, its next is deleted and point to `nullptr`, but the output suggests that `node1` is apparently Node(8430) and is not a `nullptr`.

I know that when dereferencing a `nullptr` it could result in undefined behavior. How can I modify this program so that after calling delete `node0`, `node1` can also become `nullptr`?

Comment: Side note, NULL is C, nullptr is C++

Comment: Setting a `next` to null won't affect the value of a variable like `node1`.

Comment: Why you think `node1` should be null. There is only single assignment to it and it is not `nullptr`. And `node1` is not an object, but pointer to object.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but`next = nullptr;` in the destructor is pointless. The object is going away; any use of any of its members after destruction results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Use smart pointers. C++11 is already very old.

Comment: node0->next and node1 should point to the same address and next is set to nullptr in destructor. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You have two variables. You assign to one, but not the other. Why should both be modified? Lets say you had `int a0 = 1; int a1 = 1; a0 = 0;`, would you be equally surprised that `a1` is still equal to `1`?

Comment: This is Undefined Bahavior: `std::cout << *node1 << " \n"; // outputs Node(8430)` called dangling pointer, it may work, it may crash, it may cause [demons fly from your nose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qxeT1nTjr).

Comment: C++ assignment is based on value semantics, not reference semantics.   `node0->next` is assigned to have the value of `node1`.  But they are distinct variables (of type `Node *`) so subsequent assignment of `node0->next` (in the destructor) does not affect the value of `node1` - there is no magical connection that makes `node1` change when `node0->next` changes.   Furthermore, the assignment `next = nullptr` in the destructor is pointless, since the entire `Node` will cease to exist immediately after the destructor (so all its members, including `node` ceases to exist also).

Comment: Actually, @Someprogrammerdude, a better example would've been `int a0 = 1; int a1 = ao; a0 = 0;`. Shocking revelation: `a1` is still 1.

Comment: The most important thing to learn about pointers is that there is nothing special about pointers. They work exactly like other primitive types, such as `int` or `bool`.

Comment: Assigning data members in a destructor is mostly meaningless - an object will be gone in a moment anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you expect is similar to this:

```
void foo(int* ptr) {
    delete ptr;
    ptr = nullptr;
}

int main() {
   int * x = new int;
   foo(x);
   assert( x == nullptr);   // NOPE !!
}
```

`ptr` is a copy of `x`. `delete ptr` deletes the dynamically allocated `int`. That does not affect the value of `x` in any way. `x` still has the same value after calling `foo`. It just is not a valid pointer anymore. The address where it points holds no `int` anymore.

Or even simpler:

```
int* a = new int;
int* b = a;
delete a;
a = nullptr;
assert( b == nullptr ); // NOPE !!!
```

Actually your misunderstanding can be traced back to an even simpler example:

```
int a = 42;
int b = a;
a = 0;
assert( b == 0); // NO !!
```

With pointers it is no different.

In your code `node0->next = node1;` a copy of the pointer is made. Then in the destructor of `node0` you delete the node pointed to by `node0->next` but that has no effect on the pointer in main.

TL;DR: Do not confuse the pointer and the pointee. `delete x` deletes the object pointed to by `x`. If you copy a pointer you have two totally independent pointers that point to the same object, assigning `nullptr` to one of them has no effect on the other.

Comment: I think my misunderstanding also stems from the fact that I thought after deleting, the pointer should be nullptr; `int* a = new int; delete a; assert(a == nullptr);`. Is it true that there is no way to check if `a` has already been deleted after calling `delete a`? Is the most elegant solution to use `shared_ptr`?

Comment: @ZhangColeman no there is no way. The drop in replacement for a raw owning pointer is `std::unique_ptr`. `std::shared_ptr` is for shared ownership

Comment: @ZhangColeman *I thought after deleting, the pointer should be nullptr;* -- C++ is not going to waste cycles setting pointers to `nullptr` when `delete` is issued.  If I write C++ code, I don't want C++ to do extra things that I didn't ask for, especially things that will slow down performance.  This is the C++ philosophy -- it is called the [zero overhead principle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/Zero-overhead_principle#:~:text=The%20zero%2Doverhead%20principle%20is,could%20reasonably%20write%20by%20hand.)

Comment: There are legitimate reasons why you might want to check if a pointer was deleted - but those require far more in-depth knowledge and should ONLY be used after other options are exhausted and the profiler and performance-tests have shown that to be the critical section.

Comment: @ABaumstumpf not sure what you mean. The question is about OP expecting one pointer chaning its value when they call `delete` on another pointer (where both point to the same object). Nitpick: Its not the pointer that gets deleted but the pointee

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai you can get the behaviour OP wants by creating more involved constructors and a lot more fragile and in general should not be used... but for the sake of completeness i'll give a short simple example.

Comment: @ABaumstumpf "How can I modify this program so that after calling delete node0, node1 can also become NULL?" this is what OP wants. And it is not possible (without altering types of `node0` or `node1`)

Comment: `assert( x == nullptr);   // NOPE !!` is quite misleading as it suggests that the assertion will fail.  In fact the program fails before reaching the assertion.  Reading `x` has become undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt dereferencing `x` is undefined, reading x is not afaik

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: Nope, you cannot even compare it to `nullptr`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1866693/103167 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1866470/103167  Although it's conditionally-supported (implementation-defined) rather than UB.  https://eel.is/c++draft/conv#lval-3.3

Answer (score 0):

There already is the answer by 463035818_is_not_an_ai which explains the misunderstanding - but there is the second part to this: It can be done - kinda.

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
public:
  int id;
  Node *next;
  Node **holder{ nullptr};
  explicit Node(int id ) : id(id), next(nullptr) {}
  Node(int id, Node** ptr) : id(id), next(nullptr), holder(ptr) {}

  ~Node() {
    std::cout << "Node with id(" << id << ") destructed \n";
    delete next;
    if( holder ) *holder = nullptr; // make sure not to write to nullptr
  }

  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Node &node) {
    os << "Node(" << node.id << ")";
    return os;
  }
};
```

Capture the address of the pointer that holds the node.

```
int main() {
  Node *node0;
  Node *node1;
  node0 = new Node(0, nullptr);
  node1 = new Node(1, &node1);
  node0->next = node1;

  // delete node1; // causes double-free
  delete node0; // outputs Node(0) destructed\nNode(1) destructed
  node0 = nullptr;
  std::cout << (nullptr == node0) << '\n'; // outputs 1
  std::cout << (nullptr == node1) << '\n'; // outputs 0
  //std::cout << *node1 << " \n"; // will crash
  return 0;
}
```

This would be a "simple" way of achieving the outcome you expected but it would be exceedingly bad style and error-prone. In general you do not want a dynamically allocated object to know who/where it is held from and this simple example would just work with a single point - nothing prevents you from creating another copy of the pointer before that.

Having a list where a parent-node deletes the child-node also can lead to nasty errors as shown by the line `delete node1;` - when deleting node0 it will still try to delete node1 yet again causing a double-free.