# IUnknown.Release standard implementation race condition?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, com

Here is a standard (not to say recommended) way of implementing ***Release*** method of the **IUnknown**  **COM** interface (directly taken from MSDN):

```
ULONG CMyMAPIObject::Release()
{
    // Decrement the object's internal counter.
    ULONG ulRefCount = InterlockedDecrement(m_cRef);
    if (0 == m_cRef)
    {
        delete this;
    }
    return ulRefCount;
}
```

I was wondering if a race condition could occur if the apartment model is not **STA**:

- say there is one reference left
- thread 1 releases it by calling *Release*
- it runs and is stopped just before `delete this`
- thread 2 is scheduled and obtain a new reference to the object, e.g. by calling *QueryInterface* or *AddRef*
- thread 1 continue to execute and runs `delete this`
- thread 2 is left with an invalid object

For me the only way to ensure consistency would be to create a flag, say *deleted*, lock the whole critical section, i.e. all the *Release* method except the return, and set the flag to *true*.

And in the *AddRef* and *QueryInterface* methods check this flag, and if it's set then reject the request for new reference.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does thread 2 obtain that new reference? You should not allow re-using an object which ref count has become zero. You'd rather create a new object to give to the thread 2. And if you hold a strong reference to the object somewhere across threads, thread 1 would not make the object's ref count zero.

Comment: @Noseratio: thanks for your response. OK, so in the *QueryInterface* and *AddRef* methods I must check that the counter is not already 0 (this boolean is my flag). For *QueryInterface* I can make the caller aware of the rejection of its request, but for *AddRef* is there any standard pattern? If I return 0, then the caller should check the return value, but this value is "intended to be used only for test purposes" according to the MSDN documentation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> thread 2 is scheduled and obtain a new reference to the object, e.g. by calling QueryInterface or AddRef

It can only do this if it already has a reference to IUnknown or one of the other interfaces implemented by the object.  For which an AddRef() call was made earlier.  The reference count can thus *never* be decreased to a value less than 1 by another thread's Release call.

Do write the code correctly, you must compare ulRefCount to 0, not m_cRef.

Comment: Correct! Thanks *Hans*. :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a race condition in the code, but it's not the one in your example.  This implementation of `Release()` has a race condition that can cause undefined behavior (typically a "double free"). Consider:

1. Thread 1 & Thread 2 have a reference to the object (`m_cRef` == 2)
2. Thread 1 calls `Release()` and is interrupted immediately after running `InterlockedDecrement()` (`m_cRef` == 2)
3. Thread 2 calls `Release()` and runs to completion, so `m_cRef` == 0 so it calls `delete this`.
4. Thread 1 resumes at the line `if (0 == m_cRef)` and `m_cRef` == 0 so it calls `delete this` again causing undefined behavior (typically a "double free" error).

The correct implementation is:

```
ULONG CMyMAPIObject::Release()
{
    // Decrement the object's internal counter.
    ULONG ulRefCount = InterlockedDecrement(m_cRef);
    if (0 == ulRefCount) //<<<< THIS FIXES THE PROBLEM
    {
        delete this;
    }
    return ulRefCount;
}
```

The if check needs to be on the local `ulRefCount` variable.  Because `InterlockedDecrement()` returns the value that it decremented to, `ulRefCount` will only be zero on Thread 2's call so `delete this` will only be called on Thread 2.

The `if (0 == m_cRef)` is accessing shared state without a lock and is not safe.

See the answer to this question as well: [Why does this implementation of COM IUnknown::Release work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866456/why-does-this-implementation-of-com-iunknownrelease-work)

Comment: thanks for pointing this race condition. In my code I always use *ulRefCount* so it's fine, but I've never considered this double free issue. Good point. :)

Comment: This is all good, but I'll say that it's not the potential "double free" that is the first problem to occur, it may happen that the comparison runs into undefined behavior because the member variable belongs to an already deleted object.