# Calling delete this from OnOk in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, self-destruction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should “delete this” be called from within a member method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861912/should-delete-this-be-called-from-within-a-member-method)

Is is correct to call delete from OnOk event handler function, as in the code below.

```
void CTestDlg::OnOK() 
{
    CDialog::OnOK();

    this->DestroyWindow();
    delete this;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't have been closed, it's not a duplicate, but a specific MFC modeless dialog question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're trying all that because the dialog instance is modeless?

In that case you [shouldn't be calling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66b3y2ab%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the base class OnOK() from your override, but only DestroyWindow().

If you have to `delete this` then an override of `PostNcDestroy()` is the [appropriate place](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1651/Tutorial-Modeless-Dialogs-with-MFC).

Comment: Can you please explain, why not calling CDialog::OnOk()?

Comment: OnOK() is really meant for DoModal() whereas yours is modeless and needs to be closed down more appropriately.

Comment: Will it make any difference, if one call even for Modeless dialog?


Sorry if this question irritate you! As I am not getting source file where CDialog::OnOk() is defined.